# How to make a SP list by using SQL Data through PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, query, sql

I have the following assignment:
Our campus has a SQL database filled with printers. My job is to create a SharePoint list that printer constructors can use to read certain counters. 
This will be done using PowerShell.

Example: Constructor ABC wants to know the amount of pages printed on printer D between date F and date G. He can enter the name/serial no and date(s) on a SharePoint site, which will then display the number he is looking for.

I've received some example code to add items to a list in PowerShell, but the whole process is lost on me. I know some basic things but all in all I'm still a beginner when it comes to SharePoint and PowerShell.

I'm looking for some general guiding steps to complete this assignment, e.g. "first, write this and then link this,...", so I can plan the assignment accordingly.

This question might be too vague and might not belong here, but trying never hurt anyone!

Thanks,
Stu

Answer (score 1):

Use below link to import sql server data to SPList:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/insert-data-from-sql-server-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html

Once you have data into SPList, then data can be filtered based on any condition.

Comment: This is for SP Online, correct? I'm using SP 2013 and your provided method does not seem to work, because I can't use 'Get-SPWeb'.

Comment: Why can't you use Get-SPWeb? This is available in SP2013.

Comment: I always get the following error:
'Get-SPWeb : The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....'
when I use the code the link provides.

Comment: Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell in powershell